# Video streaming for different extensions

Tags: flash, video, streaming, video-player

Please guide me for the technique by which i can stream each type of video formats on my website using flash player, As much as I found that its not possible to stream all video formats for flash players because they do not support all of them, but how can youtube and dropbox manage to stream any uploaded formats, can any one tell me how are the doing this do they creates a copy for every video in flash compatible format

Answer (score 1):

Videos on YT are converted to the appropriate format after they're uploaded.

It's possible to do so with for example ffmpeg library that would be installed on the server. Check out http://www.ffmpeg.org/

Flash supports flv/f4v/mp4 formats.